# logout a user automatically when the browser window is closed- salesforce

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

I have a basic question about salesforce session, i want to logout my users automatically when they close the browser window.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score -1):

This is an old thread but I thought I would go ahead and share my work around...

Add a controller to your site home page, and in the init action, redirect to secure page, if it is not already a secure page.

```
public PageReference init() {
        String currentURL = Site.getCurrentSiteUrl();
        if (!startsWith(currentUrl, 'https://')) {
            return redirect(currentURL.replace('http://', 'https://'));
        }

        return null;
    }
```